# Counting Duplicates in another column in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, search, count, increment

The outcome I am trying to achieve is illustrated in the image below. Here is how I have set it up right now.

1. **Column A** is a list of unique numbers created by dragging down and filling series
2. **Column B** is a list of project names. Data validation restricts its inputs to columns E3:E6. This is user selected
3. **Column C** is unique and must not have any duplicates. This is achieved by setting data validation to the following equation `=COUNTIF($C:$C,C2)=1`. The Task ID should be the corresponding Project code (from cell F) of the Project Name of the cell on the same row, but in column B, then a hyphen, then the 3 digit incremented code. It is, however, user entered at the moment.

How can I make it so the user does not have to enter the task ID. Instead, I want it to be automatically generated when the user selects the Project in column B.

**NOTE** this should not affect the outcome, however, in my case, the Project Names and Project Codes for data validation are on another sheet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B2 use,

```
=index(e:e, match(left(c2, 2), f:f, 0))
```

If your project codes are not always 2 characters but are separated from the extraneous information by a hyphen use,

```
=index(e:e, match(left(c2, find("-", c2&"-")-1), f:f, 0))
```

It appears I interpreted the lookup backwards. To lookup the Task ID prefix from the Project Codes and supply an increment suffix use the following in C2,

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(B2,E:E,0))&TEXT(COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2), "-000")
```

Comment: I think that's doing the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want to put an equation in C2

Comment: If I change it to `=INDEX(F:F, MATCH(B2, E:E, 0))` it achieves, the desired affect, but now how do I count the number of occurrences of the b2 in all of column b?

Comment: Thanks. Here is how I solved it `=CONCAT(INDEX(F:F, MATCH(B3, E:E, 0)),"-",TEXT(COUNTIF($B$2:B3,B3),"000"))`

Comment: Encountered a problem.  It does not work if the cells being validated against (E and F) are in a different worksheet (example!E and example!F)

Comment: Use `=INDEX('Example'!F:F,MATCH(B2,'Example'!E:E,0))`. It works on another worksheet; it even works on a closed external workbook. Now that you are going in this direction, hte [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is another option.

Comment: ya I figured it out, the problem was that I was using `=INDEX('Example'!F:'Example'!F,MATCH(B2,'Example'!E:'Example'!E,0))`